# need upload script for uploading files larger than 4GB

Tags: looking-for-a-script, uploading

I have users that need to upload files larger than 4GB. What's the best way to do this? Most upload scripts fail with large objects. Also, when sending huge data sets, TCP/IP's 1-in-4billion promise of consistency will frequently result in file corruption.

Is there a good flash or java uploader that will chunk and compute MD5 hashes on every chunk?

Comment: I would avoid the HTTP protocol for transmitting files that large. You may want to look into creating your own protocol that implements error checking, etc.

Comment: It's not just 'upload scripts' that will fail, the server configuration might reject it.

Comment: Creating my own protocol is probably a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

> I have users that need to upload files larger than 4GB. What's the best way to do this?

FTP (SFTP/FTPS) - not http at all

Comment: FTP has no error checking.

Comment: @vy32 FTP doesn't, but neither does HTTP. But you shouldn't be using FTP anyway. If you use SFTP, not only are file resumes better supported, but it also does a checksum every 32kb. Also, TCP/IP has error detection/correction using checksums. Not only that, but most physical layer protocols also have error correction built in (e.g. Ethernet uses CRC-32 checksums).

Comment: For the record, Ethernet does not use CRC-32 checksums. FTP is based on TCP which uses a 32-bit IP checksum and a 32-bit TCP checksum. However, the problem with a 32-bit checksum is that you'll get an undetected error with 1 in 4 billion probability.

Comment: @vy32: Yes, [it does](https://www.google.com/search?q=ethernet+32+crc). The final field in an Ethernet frame is a CRC-32 checksum. And according to the IETF TCP and UDP use 16-bit CRCs, not 32-bit. But, as I said, you should be using SFTP anyways, so you'd have error correction across 3 layers. And SFTP uses SHA or MD5 for its checksums. So the chances of a randomly induced error slipping through is vanishingly small (even more so than CRC-32 on top of CRC-16).

Comment: Well, we see transmission errors all the time. They are not vanishingly slow. We are doing transfers of 10TB and 100TB sized objects and we routinely see a transmission error every 1-10 TB.

Comment: You are correct, I was wrong; Ethernet does have CRC. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame. My understanding was that most long-haul did not move over Ethernet, but that was back in the 1990s.

Comment: @vy32: Is that over FTP or SFTP? If SFTP, were you using MD5 or SHA? Those are pretty large transfers, far beyond anything I've tried over the internet. I would suggest you ask a question on Serverfault or Superuser for the best method/protocol/app to use to transfer that volume of data. Once you establish that, then it should be a simple matter of finding a web-based interface for the chosen protocol.

Comment: Also, in theory if you use something like rysync, then errors shouldn't matter because it uses delta encoding. If the checksum fails to match up, you can just re-run the transfer and it should only retransfer the corrupt segments. But I don't know how efficient delta encoding is with different types of data and different file sizes.